# Rails3: gem is not loaded

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.2, rubygems

Using the serialize_with_options gem in rails 3 application.

gemfile

```
gem 'serialize_with_options'
```

in model (User.rb)

```
 serialize_with_options(:less) do
    only :id, :name
  end
```

there is an exception thrown when application is booted:

```
NoMethodError: undefined method `serialize_with_options' for User
```

any clue why/how rails is not loading gem?

Comment: Can you access `SerializeWithOptions` module in console?

Comment: No .. even the `rails console` command is giving the same error. (FYI:using production env)

Comment: `User` is an `ActiveRecord::Base` subclass, right?

Comment: Looks like this gem is a bit outdated. Maybe that's the case.

Comment: @muistooshort: yes it is inherited from `ActiveRecord::Base`.